# In Frosty the Snowman (1969), what is Christmas snow?

Tags: frosty-the-snowman

Is Christmas snow any snow that falls in the Christmas season which is between Dec 1 and Dec 25?

Comment: I swear you already asked this. Did it get deleted?

Comment: You might be confusing it with the other 5 million Frosty questions of similarly questionable worth.

Comment: a) This is trivia (good reason to vtc) and b) Who defined the "Christmas Season" as Dec 1 - 25?

Answer (score 1):

It seem pretty clear from the narration that "a Christmas Snow" is one that happens to fall on Christmas Eve..

> And as any child can tell you, there's a certain magic to the very first snow. Especially when it falls **on the day before Christmas. For when the first snow is also a Christmas snow**,  well, something wonderful is bound to happen.

Comment: This quote does not preclude Christmas snow from one that falls other than on Christmas Eve.